# Would making a binary search tree out of a struct over a class node be bad?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, binary-search-tree

I'm not sure if i should.. or should not use a struct to create a binary search tree, the other option is to create the nodes out of a separate node class. with a data, left and right. Which one is better? And why?

heres my code for the BST

```
template <typename T>
class BST : public SearchableADT<T>
{
public:
  BST(void){    head     = NULL; numnodes = 0; }
  virtual ~BST(void);
  virtual int loadFromFile(string filename);
  virtual void clear(void);
  virtual void insertEntry(T info); 
  virtual void deleteEntry(T info); 
  virtual bool isThere(T info);
  virtual int numEntries(void); 

  //needed for comparison to AVL 
  int BST<T>::height(t_node* tPTR); 
protected:
  struct t_node
  {
      string data;
      t_node *L;
      t_node *R;
  };
  int numnodes;
  t_node* head; 
  t_node* cPTR; //current pointer
  t_node* pPTR; //parent pointer
  t_node* tPTR; //temporary pointer  
}; // end of class BST
```

Comment: The standard library already supports binary trees in the form of `std::set` and `std::map`, and you can always use another container with the binary search functions in the algorithm library (`lower_bound` / `upper_bound` / `binary_search`).

Comment: Thank you, but im just wanting to know if it is OKAY to use the struct. And if not, why a class Node would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to create two classes, one for the BST and another for the node. They are two different abstractions. A node is a simpler abstraction whose main purpose is to hold the data necessary to define a BST. A BST is a higher level abstraction. It's a collection class with its own constraints and expectations.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you understand the difference between struct and class but basically:

```
struct
```

Has public access for all of its members by default and

```
class
```

Has private access for all of its members by default.

You can achieve the same thing with both of them but many programmers, including myself, tend to use structs for POD objects (Plain Old Data) for straight up access (It makes it easier to write less).

That said, I think you should put your Node class outside in a different file since the BST and Node classes are very different. Since you gave your BST class a template, I am assuming that you are gonna use more than just the Node class, which gives more reason to separate the files for the projects that you might not use the Node class. If you aren't going to use more than just a Node class, you might consider removing the template and defining the Node struct/class inside the BST class!

Comment: No i completely understand how they're accessed, i was just wondering how they compare to eachother when using it, but the reply above you is very well done and i like it! Thank you!